# Is a dataset of Paint-like paintings available?

Tags: data-request, images

In [ML-KA](http://ml-ka.de/), a machine learning group in Karlsruhe, we recently had a discussion about features learned by CNNs. It is often said that they learn general features in the first layers which are usable for arbitrary vision tasks. One idea to check that was to apply them to paint-like paintings. By "Paint-like" I mean a specific style of image which is often created by children / non-professionals. Here is an example:

[image]

Is there a big repository of paint-like images available? (Preferably with labels / descriptions / tags / categories.)

Comment: I've just stumbled over [redditgetsdrawnbadly](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditgetsdrawnbadly). It might be an interesting source.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any open data repositories, but you could probably go to one of the commercial picture sites. They are well labeled / categorised and I suspect you could just purchase the low quality images quite cheaply. Unfortunately not open data, sorry.

Didn't spend masses of time, but the following queries in [Fotolia](https://www.fotolia.com/search?k=simple%20line%20drawn%20pictures&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Aillustration%5D=1&filters%5Bcontent_type%3Avector%5D=1&search-submit=Search) and [BigStockPhoto](http://www.bigstockphoto.com/search/simple-line-drawn-pictures/) seem useful, but you will need to go through them to choose a decent set which matches your criteria. Difficult to know with just one picture as an example.